# SalesForce: How to automate managed package installation in Continuous Integration

Tags: ant, package, salesforce, managed, force.com

I have successfully set up continuous integration process using TeamCity for non-SalesForce projects, but **need help with automating SalesFoce manage packages installation**.

To migrate metadata from source to target org, I used ant migration tool, but how to do in case of managed packages?

**Questions:**

1. How will TeamCity know that the new package has been created? I may watch the changes in source code tool, but not in the cloud where the created package is stored.
2. How to get the latest version of the package from the cloud? I need to compare the versions of the packages: the installed one and the new one
3. How to install the package?

Please help.

Comment: I'm upvoting your question because I'm looking for pretty similar thing (not related to managed package, but to manual actions in CI process). Possibly someone will provide useful for you answer in my question, so I leave here link to it. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039136/automatize-manual-tasks-after-deployment-of-salesforce-project

Answer (score 0):

I checked SF documentation and found that SF API provides ability to install, upgrade and uninstall Managed Packages. Also it provides ability to run some Apex code after these actions. I think, you need to move in this way. Here is [related documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_api_introduction.htm).